# How to resolve this Stripe Payment integration Error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_STPPaymentCardTextField", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in PaymentViewController.o


"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Stripe", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in StripeHandlerViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  objc-class-ref in PaymentViewController.o
 (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_StripeHandlerViewController)


"_OBJC_CLASS_$_STPAPIClient", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in StripeHandlerViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in PaymentViewController.o
  "_StripeDomain", referenced from:
  -[StripeHandlerViewController createBackendChargeWithToken:completion:] in StripeHandlerViewController.o
  ___71-[StripeHandlerViewController createBackendChargeWithToken:completion:]_block_invoke in StripeHandlerViewController.o
  -[PaymentViewController save:] in PaymentViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I try to integrate Stripe payment in my old project, so i added some example file in myproject. it show this errors so i google it and add this file to Build phase--> Compile sources but it still show this error.

Please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

You are trying to build this for the simulator and the linker is telling you that the library is missing the binary for the x86_64 (simulator). I'm not familiar with that library but you are most likely missing the framework that's specifically for the simulator or that library doesn't have simulator support.